# error bulk insert in php! what should I do?

Tags: php, bulkinsert

I use this code

```
$values = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea_name']);
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `table` (`col`) VALUES ($values)");
```

Data should be string. How I can convert it to string? I want to make each row to a record! make my code complete !

```
print_r($values);

Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 0 [10] => 1 [11] => 2 [12] => 3 [13] => 4 [14] => 5 [15] => 6 [16] => 7 [17] => 8 [18] => 9 [19] => 0 )
```

I want to know how to Insert this values to Mysql database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bulk insert from php form textarea? array bulk error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411893/how-to-bulk-insert-from-php-form-textarea-array-bulk-error)

Comment: by using explode for '\n', are you getting array ?

Comment: @TBI yes explode output an array.

Comment: use print_r($values) and post your array in the question

Comment: can you say what error you are getting or check if the database connected properly

Comment: The error is "Array to string conversion"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($values as $value){
 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `table` (`col`) VALUES ($value)");
}
```

Edited:

```
   <form action="test.php" method="post">
     <textarea name="textarea_name">test content......</textarea>
     <input type="submit" />
   </form>
```

In test.php

```
 include('dbconnection.php');
 if(isset($_POST['textarea_name'])){
  $values=explode("\n",$_POST['textarea_name'])
  foreach($values as $value){
   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `table` (`col`) VALUES ($value)");
  }
 }
```

you want like this?

Comment: please print the value of $_POST['textarea_name'];

Comment: print_r($_POST['textarea_name']); run this query

Comment: And how to use it for inserting?

Comment: Can you use it:
$values =$_POST['textarea_name'];
foreach($values as $value){
 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `table` (`col`) VALUES ($value)");
}

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Again!

Comment: I want to make each row of textarea text to a record.

Comment: I have edited my post, added "if(isset($_POST['textarea_name'])){ " In test.php can you try ?

Comment: Please pay attention that I want to make each row of textarea text to a record.
the text include {/n} for make values apart.

Comment: updated answer will not work...where you have define the row of textarea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = explode("\r\n", $_POST['textarea_name']);

//echo "<pre>";print_r($values);exit;

foreach($values as $value){
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `table` (`col`) VALUES ('$value')");
}
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: will you post the content for $_POST['textarea_name'] ?

Comment: I want to make each row of textarea text to a record.

Comment: Its simple
[<textarea name="name" id="id" rows="20" cols="11"></textarea>]